# How do I get Cupid Snoopy to shoot people?

Tags: snoopys-street-fair

I  downloaded the Valentine's Day update, and Snoopy now has a Cupid costume and can shoot people with love arrows.

Problem is, I have no idea how to make that happen.

How can I get him to shoot people?

Comment: I think you need [arrows first,](http://getsatisfaction.com/beeline_games/topics/little_cupid_shot_at_me_i_am_in_love_with_snoopys_street_fair) "They are a little hard to find due to their small size."  After that, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like they might work like his other costumes - you tapped an item found on the ground. Might be little arrows or something. I will keep my eye out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find a small red heart with an arrow through it. It is quite small so it was hard to find at first. But once you see one, it's easier to spot them. Snoopy takes the heart then runs and shoots an arrow at one of the kids at the fair, somewhat like he did with the snowballs.

Answer (score 4):

I zoomed in and I found a heart with an arrow through it.  I pushed it and Snoopy shot a love arrow.